# Creating an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let there be $W=Span\{(1,0,1),(1,2,3)\}$ sub-space of $V^3$ find an orthonormal basis for $V^3$

So at first I have found 2 orthonormal vectors $e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,-1)$ and $e_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$, which vector can I take to create the third orthonormal vector?

Comment: What role does $W$ play in the question?

Comment: @ShaharEven-DarMandel it is a subspace of $V\in\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: And how did you use it in coming up with the first two vectors?

Comment: It look's like you've picked $e_1$ and $e_2$ out of nowhere. How did you come up with them? What part do $W$ play? That it's a subspace is obvious, but what more? Otherwise you could pick $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ - what's wrong with that?

Comment: If (a, b, c) is normal to W then its dot product with the two spanning vectors of W will be 0. You are going to normalize this vector so may as well take a = 1. The dot product will now give you two simultaneous equations for b and c,

Comment: I used gram schmidt on both (1,0,1),(1,2,3) to get $e_1,e_2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take ${1\over\sqrt{6}}(1,-2,1)$.

**Edited**:

I want to find a vector orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$ and also to $(1,1,1)$. I know that if $v$ is any vector orthogonal to these two, then the three of them together form an orthogonal basis to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So assume $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$. Then :

$$x\cdot 1+y\cdot 0 + y\cdot (-1) = 0$$

therefore, if $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$, we must have

$$x = z$$

Now, among all vectors $(x,y,z)$ that are orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$ I want to find one orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ too. Now if $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ then

$$x\cdot 1 + y\cdot 1 + z\cdot 1 = 0$$

so

$$x + y + z = 0$$

and I already know that $x=z$ so

$$x + y + x = 0$$

so

$$2x = -y$$

So far I have shown that if $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to both the vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ then necessarily $x=z$ and $2x=-y$. This means that once we know $x$, we also know $y$ and $z$, so the vector has the form $(x,-2x,x)$. Conversely, every vector $(x,y,z)$ of the form $(x,-2x,x)$ is orthogonal to both the vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,1,1)$, as can be verified by calculating the scalar product of $(x,-2x,x)$ with the vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,1,1)$. For example,

$$(x,-2x,x)\cdot (1,1,1) = x-2x+x = 0$$

I leave the verification that $(x,-2x,x)$ is orthogonal to $(1,0,-1)$ to the readers.

So now I know that every choice of $x$ gives me a vector $(x,-2x,x)$ orthogonal to both the vectors above. I therefore choose $x=1$ and obtain the vector $(1,-2,1)$. I now compute it's norm and find that it is $\sqrt{6}$, so the normalized vector is ${1\over\sqrt{6}}(1,-2,1)$.

No need for Gram Schmidt here.

Comment: Which vector did you take?

Comment: I took the vector ${1\over\sqrt{6}}(1,-2,1)$.

Comment: Yes but you had to take a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is linear independent of the two other?

Comment: It is orthogonal to each of them, so in particular it is linearly independent of their linear span.

Comment: How you take to orthonormal vectors and complete it to a basis?

Comment: @gbox  I have edited my answer to explain in plenty of detail how I got the vector. Hope it helps.

Comment: @hardmath  referring someone to a link with the Gram-Schmidt process for this problem is quite cruel.

Comment: Your edit is indeed a kindness.  I suspect the OP used Gram-Schmidt already, and the sense of asking "Which vector did you take?" might have been "What third vector did you choose to apply the third iteration of Gram-Schmidt to?"  Of course, up to sign, the final orthonormal basis element is determined by the first two (in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: @hardmath Yes, you are probably right. Of course, had the OP mentioned that he got stuck in the final stage of GS orthogonalization process, I suspect my answer would have been a little different.

Comment: you used the orthogonal vectors and not the orthonormal to ease the process?

Comment: @gbox - yes. I seems easier, because otherwise I would need to find a vector not in the span of the first two and then project it orthogonaly onto their span, and finally take the difference between the vector and it's projection, not forgetting to normalize.  It seems more tedious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the cross product

$e_1 \times e_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 6} (1,0,-1) \times (1,1,1) = 
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 6}(1, -2, 1)$